# How do I rewrite my query to use less temporary space?

Tags: postgresql, performance, disk-space, temporary-tables, query-performance

I'm using Postgres 9.5.  I want to identify (and then delete) rows from my table that are "duplicates" in the sense that they contain three fields that are the same, namely

```
my_object_id
name
time_in_ms
```

The table is defined like so

```
myproject_production=> \d my_object_times;
                               Table "public.my_object_times"
      Column       |            Type             |              Modifiers
-------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
 first_name        | character varying           |
 last_name         | character varying           |
 time_in_ms        | bigint                      |
 created_at        | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at        | timestamp without time zone | not null
 name              | character varying           |
 racer_id          | character varying           |
 age               | integer                     |
 city              | character varying           |
 state_id          | integer                     |
 country_id        | integer                     |
 my_object_id           | character varying           | not null
 id                | character varying           | not null default uuid_generate_v4()
Indexes:
    "my_object_times_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_my_object_times_on_country_id" btree (country_id)
    "index_my_object_times_on_my_object_id" btree (my_object_id)
    "index_my_object_times_on_state_id" btree (state_id)
    "my_object_times_name_idx" btree (upper(name::text) text_pattern_ops)
    "my_object_times_rev_name_idx" btree (reverse(upper(name::text)) text_pattern_ops)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_0fe1d25967" FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(id)
    "fk_rails_a8771b3575" FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES states(id)
    "fk_rails_ba656ceafa" FOREIGN KEY (my_object_id) REFERENCES my_objects(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "user_my_object_time_matches" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_2e7860946c" FOREIGN KEY (my_object_time_id) REFERENCES my_object_times(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "my_objects" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_dda3297b57" FOREIGN KEY (linked_my_object_time_id) REFERENCES my_object_times(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I thought this query would do the job

```
select rt1.id, rt1.name 
FROM my_object_times rt1, 
     my_object_times rt2 
where rt1.my_object_id = rt2.my_object_id 
  and rt1.name = rt2.name 
  and rt1.time_in_ms = rt2.time_in_ms 
  and rt1.id > rt2.id;
```

But I guess I have so much data, the above query is dying with the below error:

```
ERROR:  could not write block 1862514 of temporary file: No space left on device
```

This is after pointing my temporary space (`pgsql_tmp` directory) at a partition that gives it 20 GB of temp space.  So my question is, how can I rewrite the above so that it does not use as much temp space?  That is fine if it takes the query a really long time to run.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Unrelated, but. you should really learn how to use the modern explicit `JOIN` instead of the ancient and fragile implicit joins in the where clause (but it's irrelevant for your problem)

Comment: 20GB of temp space doesn't tell us much without knowing how big the underlying table is.  Also, is the query you give for the data to keep, or the data to deleted?

Answer (score 3):

Try the query using window functions which gets rid of the self join:

```
select id, name
from (
 select id, name, my_object_id, time_in_ms, 
        count(*) over (partition by name, my_object_id, time_in_ms) as cnt
 from my_object_times t1
) t 
where cnt > 1;
```

The `partition by` will still need to sort the rows, so it might be that it still needs a lot of temp space. If your server has a lot of memory, you can also increase `work_mem` for your session before running the statement.

Another possible way is to use an `exists` query instead of the self join:

```
select id, name
from my_object_times t1
where exists (select *
              from my_object_times t2
              where t1.my_object_id = t2.my_object_id 
                and t1.name = t2.name 
                and t1.time_in_ms = t2.time_in_ms 
                and t1.id <> rt2.id);
```

An index on `(my_object_id, name, time_in_ms, id)` would help for this.

Check the execution plan for both to see if one is cheaper then then other.

Comment: For both these queries, will they select all duplicate rows or only one of the two (or potentially more) duplicate rows?  My goal is to eventually delete all but one for those records that are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Start small. Run your query, but add `LIMIT 100` so you just bring back 100 duplicates. If all works, bump up the limit, etiher until it's a reasonable percentage of the total rows you expect to delete, or until you overflow tempdb again.

Once you know how many rows you can delete at a time, set up a loop. `SELECT` your rows; as long as you found rows, `DELETE` them and `SELECT` again.

It's definitely not fast. However, by limiting the number of rows you're deleting at a time, you also limit the impact on any other activity on the server.